# Satellites minerals finding capability

Tags: minerals, satellites

Just wondering with the latest satellites currently available, is it possible to locate gold which is buried under 200 ft? what is the maximum depth that satellites can look for such minerals.

Comment: Sorry, in its current form the question is a better fit for [WorldBuilding.se]. If you want to ask about detecting underwater mineral deposits from satellites, remove the king and the stone boxes from your question, and put the gold back into mineral deposits. Is the question *only* about gold, then say so, otherwise leave it out alltogether.

Comment: Thanks @JanDoggen for the comment. I just wanted to give background about my question. I just wanted to know maximum depth that satellites can look.

Comment: depends a lot on how much gold, if you are looking for gld you are either looking for changes in surface vegetation or gravity mapping both of which will need large deposits.

Comment: @John ~1 ton of gold ... This gold is in the form of coins and bars.

Comment: 1 ton of gold is a cube a little bit bigger than a foot (37 centimeters) on each side. you would have a hard time spotting it in aerial photography on the surface much less subsurface with satellite imagery.

Comment: @John Thanks for the response. So with the latest available satellite technology it is difficult to find such deep buried gold.

Comment: no with current technology its impossible, its just too small an amount to be detectable when buried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a well has a diameter of 2 metres, even 5 metres. This would be an exceedingly small target area for a satellite, some hundreds to thousands of kilometres above the Earth to find. Being buried, particularly at 200 metres depth, increases the difficulty exponentially.

Satellites are better at finding minerals on the surface, or just below the surface, not at 200 metres depth.